# simplify distance calculation (Spherical distance to degree difference)

Tags: polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

I am programming for a transportaion system which every 5 second I have to check if there are drivers nearby the start point. I know that it is not optimum solution If I loop through all thousnads drivers and calculate the distance using (LAT,LONG) so I want to simplify the calculations just by linear difference between the (LAT,LONG) of start point and the drivers to be in specific **range**. My problem is how to calculate this **RANGE** to satisfy the minimum desired distance in a specific area.

Assumptions:

list of variables: `(lat1,long1)` , `(lat2,long2)` , `(lat0,long0)`, `MINIMUM` , `RANGE`, `Distance`

1. The targt area of activity is beteewn `(lat1,long1)` and `(lat2,long2)`
2. The start Point is `(lat0,long0)` which is in bounds of area.
3. Drivers position is any point `(latD,longD)` which is in the bounds of area.
4. The real **DISTANCE** is calculated using a complex spherical formula between start point and drivers point (Please see the footnotes).
5. I want to simplify the distance check just by comparing `abs(lat0 - latD)< Range` also `abs(long0-longD)<Range` . The Range should be the minimum number which if satisfies these two formula, so the real **DISTANCE** also should be Less than the **MINIMUM**.

in brief find the relation between RANGE and MINIMM which:

if `(abs(lat0 - latD)< Range) && (abs(long0 - longD)<Range)`

So : `Distance < Minimum`

How should I calculate the **RANGE** within the defined area to satisfy all points in this area? I am aware that using a single RANGE causes the low accuracy in different points of the area but I am looking for minimum one which satisfies all points (or perhaps an optimum one).

Footnote: obviousley the **RANGE** is independent of drivers position and should be calculated using these 7 parameters (LAT0,LONG0),(LAT1,LONG1),(LAT2,LONG2) and MINIMUM.

Footnote2: The real Forumla for spherical Distance between `(Lat0,Lon0)` and `(latD,lonD)` by assuming the earth radius ([Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34486089/4700922)):

```
function distance(lat0, lon0, latD, lonD)
    p = 0.017453292519943295
    a = 0.5 - cos((latD - lat0) * p)/2 + cos(lat0 * p) * cos(latD * p) * (1 - cos((lonD - lon0) * p))/2
    distance = 12742 * arcsin(sqr(a))
end function
```

I guess I need a mapping from spherical to Cartesian system to convert that curved area to a flat square? Do you have any other idea? Do you deep dive into that complex formula to extract `latD - lat0` from the shark's mouth? :))

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): the real problem is to look for drivers close to a given position, and you have decided upon a specific solution, which is looping through all the drivers and calculate their distances to the given point to find one close enough. Then you want help with calculating a distance in a clever and efficient way. But wouldn't it be better to look for a solution where you only look at drivers close by?

Comment: But if you're going for this solution, it might be better to calculate the straight line distance between two points instead of the distance along the sphere.

Comment: @md2perpe you are right there are more shortcut solutions for this problem. For your first comment that I itterate through near cars, I need a start point to define which cars are close? I have started right here and I know that it is a feasible solution. After that I thinked to this question that what is the minimum RANGE instead of a **big** number as start point to exactly find the cars in the range not a wider range of cars.

Comment: The target area, is it the spherical rectangle with corners in $(\mathsf{lat}_1, \mathsf{long}_1)$, $(\mathsf{lat}_1, \mathsf{long}_2)$, $(\mathsf{lat}_2, \mathsf{long}_2)$, $(\mathsf{lat}_2, \mathsf{long}_1)$?

Comment: How big is the target area? Perhaps it's small enough to approximate as flat?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system

And specifically take a look at "Length of a degree" section in there, which is based on these two main articles if you wanna dive in:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_of_a_degree_of_latitude

and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_of_a_degree_of_longitude

Answer (score 1):

Is your system is running either (a) near the poles, or (b) over areas much larger than a couple of degrees of latitude?

If not, one can obtain a good first linear approximation as follows.  Pick a representative latitude, $\lambda$.  For instance, for Los Angeles, I would pick $\lambda = 34$ degrees.

Then, convert all lat-lon pairs as follows: Multiply the latitude by $111$ km, and multiply the longitude by $111 \cos \lambda$ km.  Then you can use your usual Cartesian distance formulas after that.

Answer (score 0):

Ragarding to both answers [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3365162) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3365133) I tried to find a simple formula which fits to those complex **distance factor** for Latitude and Longitude in the references. These are not global formula for a big area but are simplified to small areas with linear assumptions.

The following one shows how many Kilometers is surrounded in **1 degree of Longitude** around a given latitude:

$$LongDistanceFactor= -0.0114(lat)^2 - 0.2396(lat) + 112.57$$

and the second one shows how many kilometers is surrounded in **1 degree of latitude** around a given latitude:

$$LatDistanceFactor = 0.0139(lat) + 110.51$$

Footnotes:

1. use the absolute amount of latitude in both formula because the earth is symmetrical
2. As the formula is generated for 1 unit of degree (lat of long), so to find how many degrees equals to a given DISTANCE  you just need the ratio of `DISTANCE/LatDistanceFactor` or `DISTANCE/LongDistanceFactor` and simply add the result (by factor 1) to to the given Lat or Long.